# Visually Separating Cliques in Graphs

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I have a graph with 189 vertices, more than 10,000 edges and 20 cliques. As one can imagine, this graph is a mess when trying to display it. I'd really like to display the graph, separated into cliques.

I can find the cliques easy enough, but I'm lost when it comes to displaying. I've played around with `GraphicsRow`, but I then lose the edges between cliques. I also have seen the `VertexCoordinateRules` option in `GraphPlot`, but the idea of explicitly setting each vertex coordinate makes me nauseous.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are your cliques disjoint, that is, no vertex belongs in more than one clique? Also, it would be nice if you could provide some example data.

Comment: Instead of separating the cliques physically, have you considered colouring them using `HighlightGraph`, like in [the example for `FindGraphPartition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindGraphPartition.html)?

Comment: No, the cliques are not disjoint.

Comment: Sorry, hit enter too quickly. I haven't considered the `HighlightGraph`, it looks interesting, thank you for pointing it out. However, I wanted to separate the cliques so it was easier to visualize. Even highlighting the edges wouldn't make it much easier to read.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have V9 or V10, you can try `CommunityGraphPlot`:

```
g = ExampleData[{"NetworkGraph", "ZacharyKarateClub"}]
```

[image]

```
cliques = FindClique[g, Infinity, All]
(* {{2, 1, 3, 4, 14}, {2, 1, 3, 4, 8}, {24, 30, 33, 34}, {9, 31, 33,  34}, 
    {26, 25, 32}, {6, 7, 17}, {3, 9, 33}, {1, 4, 13}, {1, 3, 9}, {1, 6, 11}, 
    {1, 6, 7}, {1, 5, 11}, {1, 5, 7}, {2, 1, 22}, {2, 1, 20}, {2, 1, 18},
    {30, 27, 34}, {29, 32, 34}, {24, 28, 34}, {33, 23, 34}, {33, 21, 34}, 
    {33, 19, 34}, {33, 16, 34}, {33, 15, 34}, {32, 33, 34}, {25, 28}, {26, 24}, 
    {3, 29}, {3, 28}, {3, 10}, {1, 32}, {1, 12}, {2, 31}, {20, 34}, {14, 34}, {10, 34}} *)

CommunityGraphPlot[g, cliques, Method -> "Hierarchical", 
 CommunityRegionStyle -> Opacity[.1], 
 PlotLegends -> (Row[#, ","] & /@ cliques), ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

Comment: This does help visualize the cliques a bit better. Plus, I haven't seen the `PlotLegends` before, this will help. Thanks!

Comment: @shellhead, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.